# Cycles non-homologous but with the same winding number at each point outside?

Tags: algebraic-topology, plane-curves

## Problem

(Fulton's *Algebraic Topology: A First Course*, **Problem 6.28**) Can we find a closed set $X\subseteq\mathbb R^2$, such that there's a cycle $\gamma$ in $X$ not homologous to zero but for each $P\in\mathbb R^2\setminus X$, the winding number $n(\gamma,P)=0$?

## Thoughts

It seems that $X$ should be weird. Apparently, a counterexample $X$ shouldn't be totally disconnected. I have tried something like modified comb space, but didn't get any idea on constructing a counterexample.

PS: There's no counterexample when $X\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is open.

Any idea? Thanks!